# error in simple factorial program

Tags: java

```js
//WAP to find the factorial of a number using recursion.

import java.io.*;

class Factorial
{
      public static int Fact(int n)
      {
         if(n!=1)
             return n*Fact(n-1);
      }
      public static void main(String []args)
      {
            int n;
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter a number to find its factorial=");
            String s=br.readLine();
            n=Integer.parseInt(s);
            n=Fact(n);
            System.out.print("The Factorial is "+n);
       }
}
```

what are the errors i am doing here ? it shows 2 error on compilation 
1. Statement missing 
2. unreported exception must be caught or declared ...

Comment: **1.** What do you return if `if(n!=1)` is not true? **2.** `parseInt` might throw `NumberFormatException`

Comment: It is fine if you can add the Messages and mark the line where These come from.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a test driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to catch the `IOException` that can be thrown by the `readLine()` method, and you have to return something when `n==1`. Just `return 1;` in that case (since factorial of 1 is 1). So this is what you want:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Factorial {
    public static int Fact(int n) {
        if (n != 1)
            return n * Fact(n - 1);
        return 1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            int n;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter a number to find its factorial=");
            String s = br.readLine();
            n = Integer.parseInt(s);
            n = Fact(n);
            System.out.print("The Factorial is " + n);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // bla
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two thinks:

First: if n ==1 you do not return a value in ´public static int Fact(int n)`

```
 public static int Fact(int n)
 {
    if(n!=1)
        return n*Fact(n-1);
    return 1;
 }
```

Second: `br.readLine();` throws an IOException. That must be declarated in the method Header or it must be catched.

```
 public static void main(String []args) throws IOException
 {
       int n;
       BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       System.out.println("Enter a number to find its factorial=");
       String s=br.readLine();
       n=Integer.parseInt(s);
       n=Fact(n);
       System.out.print("The Factorial is "+n);
  }
```

}